# What should I spend my mega-tickets on?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

What should be most cost-effective to spend Mega-Tickets on? By that, I mean all three planets. I have Lemonade Stand, Oil Company and Doughnut Shop, but I think I can squeeze in one more mega tickets in there. Like, what would be most helpful for me for the entire way to winning Earth after the forth MT? And, what should I get first that would help me boost all the way through mid-game? Actually, spending them on Moon and Mars seem less important now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest spending the first one for Lemonade stands as they are the best source of money for quite a while. After that you want to look at your Investments to see which one pays off the most. A look at the Newspaper Unlocks is also highly suggested.

I went with Oil for the second ticket which workes out really well, others prefer going straight for Donuts. Nevertheless, there is not much time between the first and the third ticket, so if you do not screw up there will not be too much loss in efficiency as long as you take reasonable choices depending on how your businesses are running.

Comment: Thanks! But I would love if you included some info on what to use them on at the moon and mars! Mars seems really interesting... Might I use them on Profit Martians in a update in the future d:

Comment: @Luiyay: I think Mars is still too new to have concrete strategies for. The earliest they could have been opened is 3 or 4 days ago, and the price ramp for new facilities is bonkers.

Comment: Ahh. Makes sense. Also since the moon has been "re-balanced". Thanks for the input!